# Error en phpDesktop al instalar app con Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

estoy intentado crear un phpDesktop con una app que he creado con Codeigniter 4, pero al copiar el archivo a phpDesktop me saltan ciertos errores que os dejo en una imagen, ya que es mucho texto, he probado a descomentar la extension de intl del php.ini, he hecho lo que sugiere en la documentacion public $baseURL = '/'; asi como el index_page, no tengo mas ideas ni encuentro mas ayuda, alguna idea? muchas gracias[image: Errores PHPDesktop]

Answer (score 0):

Faltaba descomentar de php.ini varias extensiones, tras esto seguia dando error, no habia un php.ini de referencia como pude ver en phpinfo(); copie desde Powershell el archivo de php.ini-development para crear un php.ini, y una vez dentro use php -m para ver las extensiones que habia activas, vi que no se estaban cogiendo las extensiones necesarias asique cree un extension_dir con el path correcto, tras esto funciona. Espero que a alguien le ayude algiun dia.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).